# WP-CLI e Drush em contêineres Docker isolados

Tags: wordpress, docker, drupal

Estou começando a usar contêneres Docker para instanciar ambientes locais de desenvolvimento, principalmente para WordPress e Drupal.

Duas ferramentas que uso muito no meu workflow são o wp-cli e o drush. Seguindo o (pouco que aprendi da) filosofia do Docker, eu deixo o banco de dados em um conteiner, o CMS em outro (ligado ao bd com `--link`), e a ferramenta CLI em um terceiro conteiner (ligado ao bd com `--link` e usando as pastas do CMS com `--volumes-from`).

**Eu consigo abrir no navegador o Drupal rodando containerizado**.

Aparece a tela de instalação, eu informo os parâmetros de conexão e a instalação conclui com sucesso. Me parece que o Drush é que, por algum motivo, dá erro na hora de acessar os outros conteiners.

Em teoria, devia funcionar. Na prática, só está funcionando pro wp-cli. Acontece que já funcionou pro drush, e eu não consigo, de jeito nenhum, lembrar o que foi que eu fiz de diferente pra que parasse de funcionar.

Uso Docker version 1.10.3, build f476348/1.10.3 (fedora 23) no trabalho e fedora 24 em casa (não conferi a versão), nos dois o mesmo erro.

---

#### Como eu instancio os contêineres

WordPress: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ruda-almeida/36832b2a2632be985148f8950466e5ad/raw/122c6d7fe1fbd124f9a7309364ee27d35c78e71d/wp.sh

Drupal: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ruda-almeida/36832b2a2632be985148f8950466e5ad/raw/122c6d7fe1fbd124f9a7309364ee27d35c78e71d/drupal.sh

---

#### Mensagem de erro do Drush

```
Unable to load class Drush\Sql\Sql                                                                                                                  [error]
exception 'Drush\Sql\SqlException' with message 'Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush cannot find your database connection details.' in       [error]
/usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc:588
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(455): drush_sql_get_class()
#1 [internal function]: drush_sql_cli()
#2 /usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/includes/command.inc(373): call_user_func_array('drush_sql_cli', Array)
#3 /usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/includes/command.inc(224): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#4 [internal function]: drush_command()
#5 /usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/includes/command.inc(192): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#6 /usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#7 /usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#8 /usr/bin/drushes/drush-8.1.3/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#9 {main}
```